# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in AlecrimCoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I searched a lot for this issue however I can't find any solution.

The same issue is mentioned in https://github.com/Alecrim/AlecrimCoreData/issues/18 , I have done what was suggested however still I get the same error.

In `DataContext.swift`

```
let dataContext = DataContext()
class DataContext: Context {
    var profile:      Table<Profile>     { return Table<Profile>(context: self) }
}
```

In the a view controller in `viewDidLoad`

```
 let person = dataContext.profile.createEntity()
 person.email = "h@r.com.au"
 person.first_name = "a_name"
 let (success, error) = dataContext.save()
 if success {
      let count = dataContext.profile.count()
      println(count)
 }
 else {
       println(error)
 }
```

Error:
**`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`**

[image: screen shot 2015-09-11 at 1 22 45 pm]

I installed module via CocoPods